# Associative array with space in name doesn't appear

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Those are the values i use to fill out a form:

```
var champions = {
    "Azir":["Shurima's Legacy","Conquering Sands","Arise!","Shifting Sands", "Emperor's Divide"],
    "Dr. Mundo":["Shurima's Legacy","Conquering Sands","Arise!","Shifting Sands", "Emperor's Divide"]
    };
```

The problem is with space instead of Dr. Mundo it shows as Dr. is there anyway to fix this problem?

Update:

```
echo '<input class="champion" type="text" list="champions" placeholder="Champion '.$i.'" name="champno[]" required autofocus><br/>
                            <datalist id="champions"></datalist>';
```

Jquery:

```
for(var key in champions){
            if(champions.hasOwnProperty(key)){
                $('#champions').append('<option value=' + key + '>');
            }
        }
```

Comment: What "it" shows? JS does not care what characters form the key as soon as it's a string.

Comment: This seems to be working correctly for me - perhaps the issue is with some other part of the code you are using? Could you please add some context?

Comment: What you've provided in your update is not even JS (but php).

Comment: This works ``for(var key in champions){ console.log(key) }``... if you have that string as a json, then decoded it in php and iterate through it to get it's key name. Should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

quote the value:

```
for(var key in champions){
        if(champions.hasOwnProperty(key)){
            $('#champions').append('<option value="' + key + '">');
        }
    }
```

or, you should use something like this (for a demo, not tested):

```
$('#champions').append($('<option>').attr('value', key));
```